# Why can't Beam AvroIO use runtime parameters and how to use AvroIO in Dataflow templates?

Tags: serialization, avro, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I tried to use runtime parameters in Dataflow in combination with AvroIO only to run into serialization issues (`java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema`). Then I discovered AvroIO is missing from the table on the bottom of this page: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates

I guess it's due to unserializability of some Avro classes, is that true? Are there plans to work around this?

If not, how should I do it if I need to use runtime parameters in templates that write to Avro files? Do I have to give up templates and somehow make my service run and deploy the job the stadard way every time it needs to? That means a lot of additional network traffic and/or infrastructural code on my side. I kinda refuse to believe I'm the first one who needs to run templated jobs and use Avro at the same time. How do people solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using templates with a specific IO requires that the IO must accept `ValueProvider` versions of any parameters that will be filled in by templates. AvroIO has not been modified to accept `ValueProvider` arguments, so it does not yet support runtime parameters.

I am not sure where you are getting the serializable exception or how you are passing a `RuntimeValueProvider` to `AvroIO` given the above. To make this work, `AvroIO` would need to change to support appropriate parameterization -- likely taking a schema string -- at which point you should be able to pass it a `RuntimeValueProvider` of the Schema.

Comment: Avro IO _does_ support value providers: `org.apache.beam.sdk.io.AvroIO.Write#to(org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider<java.lang.String>)` (Beam SDK 2.0.0)

Comment: Indeed it does. I was looking at AvroIO.read(), but AvroIO.write() does support ValueProviders. Looking at the implementation, it causes it to use an anonymous inner class which captures fields of the Write class that are non serializable. https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/3538 should fix this once submitted.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and fix, will update you as we test it once it's merged.